# Login with different account

Tags: support, android-app

I want to login with another account but Google smart lock automatically login with existing account.

What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Can you delete your device's cached data in the path `Settings -> Storage -> Cached data` and try?

Comment: Above method does not work.

Comment: What exactly happens when you log out?

Comment: Automatically login in with the same account using GOOGLE SMART LOCK.

Comment: I'm seeing the same as the Asker. I have two Google accounts defined on my phone. Logging out on the Stack Exchange app and then trying to log in does not give me a choice of which account to use.